# Bind a method to each item in an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having difficulty figuring out the syntax for binding a function to each item in an object array in JavaScript/Angular.

I've tried various approaches, and while probably not syntactically correct, I feel like the approach I have here is logically on the right track.

```
var module = angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('controller', function () {
    var vm = this;

    vm.foo = 5;
    vm.bars = [
      {
        price: 1000
      },
      {
        price: 2000
      }
    ];

    var qty = function () {
      return vm.foo / this.price;
    };

    for(var i = 0; i < vm.bars; i++) {
      vm.bars.bind(vm.bars[i], qty);
    }
  });
```

My thought is that binding each item's `this` to itself, would be the best way to allow each item to reference its own `price` property in the `qty()` function, which lives outside of the object.

I'm basically just trying to avoid copy/pasting a function as a property of each item when setting up the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve here, but if you want to add a `qty` function to all the elements, it can be done like:

```
var module = angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('controller', function () {
    var vm = this;

    vm.foo = 5;
    vm.bars = [
      {
        price: 1000
      },
      {
        price: 2000
      }
    ];

    var qty = function () {
      return vm.foo / this.price;
    };

    vm.bars.forEach(function(bar){
      bar.qty = qty;
    })


  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) (Immediately Invoked Function Expression).

```
for(var i = 0; i < vm.bars; i++) {
  (function(i){
    vm.bars.bind(vm.bars[i], qty);
  )(i);
}
```

Comment: What I have (and thus, what you have) is not valid syntactically correct. I get what you're trying to do, but I'm pretty sure the usage of `bind` is not correct. Due to the error I (and you) would receive that states, `vm.bars.bind is not a function.`

Comment: I see now. may be you are trying to do this: vm.qty = function () {
      return vm.foo / this.price;
    };

    for(var i = 0; i < vm.bars; i++) {
      vm.qty.bind(vm, vm.bars[i]);
    }